# Gmail extension - possibilities. Gmail gadget or Google Apps Script

Tags: plugins, google-apps-script, gmail, google-gadget

I'm wondering if it is possible to extend Gmail, by adding a button in email context menu or other control. My Goal is to export mail or selected mails to external server.
Is it possible to accomplish that using Gmail Gadget or Google Apps Script?
If adding a custom control isnt possible i will accept any other way to export mails and integrate gmail with external system.

Answer (score 2):

To extend your gmail interface, you can write a contextual gadget. See https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets for getting started.

You can also achieve the same i.e. read an email and post it to an external server by using Google Apps Script. [Read the documentation of GMailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) to get started

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that it is possible to use google apps script to get access to users emails. But i do not know how to add a button (or something) to enable gmail user to invoke google apps script and export selected mails when he wants. Is it possible to add for example gmail sidebar gadget which will execute/invoke google apps script, which exports mails (currently i'm trying to achive such thing but i have a problem with invoking google apps script from sidebar gadget)?

Comment: One question about gadgets. Do I necessarily need to have a Google Apps domain to create gadgets?

Thank you!

Comment: No. Anyone can create/use a GMail contextual gadget

Comment: That is not correct, you need a Google Apps domain to install a gadget, as Google has deprecated the run any gadget lab

Answer (score 1):

GMailApp doesn't support UIs and Dialogs as well as Events and Triggers.